# Is there a way to not need to regenerate the model with Core Data iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, model

Say I generated an entity (User) in Model.xcdatamodeld with attributes firstName,lastName, dateCreated and so on. And then I generated a User.h, User.m

Then later on I realize I forgot to put an extra attribute into the User model.

Right now, everytime I have to delete User.h and User.m when I add a new attribute because somehow the compiler doesn't recognize the new attribute I put in.

Is there a way to note delete the generated files?

Comment: offtopic: you could use mogenerator (https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) to generate your custom NSManagedObject classes.

Comment: My Xcode overwrites the existing .m/.h file (after a confirmation dialog) if I regenerate the NSManagedObject subclasses. I do not have to delete the files manually before.

Comment: I'm with meccan on this one. mogenerator is an indispensable tool when working with CoreData models (it's also available using Homebrew.)

Comment: @meccan, not offtopic at all. mogenerator is exactly the solution to this problem. In my experience, if you're using CoreData without mogenerator, you're almost certainly doing it wrong. I wish Apple would integrate the mogenerator approach directly into Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just adding a new attribute, just add a new property to the files you are generating, and add  @dynamic propertyName on the implementation file.

On an unrelated note: make sure you are assigning class prefix to the classes you are generating as NSManagedObject subclasses from your model. "User" might be a system class, and you will get random runtime error messages and crashes.